# Where is my SQL Server 2008 instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 and SQL 2008 R2 installed on my machine.

Whenever I start `SQL Server Management Studio` from Server 2008 R2 Menu. 
where Server Name is `.\SqlExpress` or `mymachine\SqlExpress` and run

```
select @@version
```

I always see `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5057.00 (Intel X86)`

How can I access my SQL Server 2008 instance? Reading all the existing questions on SO I think I have messed up between Default Instance and Named Instance.

Could you please advise what can be done in this case.

I don't want to reinstall SQL Server 2008 or remove SQL Server 2005 instance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look at your services control panel - the instance names usually appear in the service name. You access the default instance by just `servername` without the backslash, or I think you can also use `servername\mssqlserver` for the default

Comment: Why Close for Questions?

Comment: @Rup like i said i want to access Sql Sevrer 2008 instance

Comment: Someone (wasn't me) thinks this is a server administration question and would have been better posted on StackOverflow's server administration site, http://serverfault.com

Comment: OK, so you'll need to check that it's running and find out its instance name. You can look in a number of places for that but I'd suggest you look at the services control panel. Actually I don't see it in your screenshot there. Is it definitely installed on that box?

Comment: I have menu called as "Sql Sever 2008 R2" so pretty sure it has been installed. In services panel - only on Sql Sevrer (SqlExpress) option is displayed.

Comment: OK, but that might just mean you've installed the client tools and not the database engine itself. For whatever reason it doesn't look like the database engine is installed: I'd suggest you re-run the 2008R2 installer and make sure it's installed / install it again.

Comment: @Rup reinstall resolved issue and i can see 2 Sql servcies in Services control Panel. thanks. If submit your assistance as a answer below -i can mrk it as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your control panel screenshot it doesn't look like you've got two SQL Server instances installed, so for whatever reason it looks like the SQL 2008 R2 database engine hasn't been installed correctly. You should re-run the 2008R2 installer and make sure it's installed or install it again.